# Some identity related to Euler's identity

Tags: complex-numbers, alternative-proof, geometric-series, exponential-sum

Let $n\geq 2$, and $z=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$. Then, for $1\leq m\leq n-1$
we have the identity:
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}z^{jm}=0.
$$
Considering a proof of the identity, we can use an idea about periodicity from the unit circle. I am wondering if there is another way to prove it.

Comment: Please explain the proof you have in mind in more detail.  We can't give you an alternative proof if we don't know what your original proof is.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Briefly speaking, the proof is in this way. For $gcd(m,n)=1$, we can verify that the left-hand side is $z^0+z^1+\cdots+z^{n-1}$. Let $gcd(m,n)=d$. Then, $z^0+z^m+\cdots+z^{\frac{n}{d}m}$ appears $d$ times in the left-hand side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that sum of complex unit roots is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891875/proof-that-sum-of-complex-unit-roots-is-zero)

Comment: Not exactly the same, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the sum is a geometric sum; we get
$$(1-z^m)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}z^{jm}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}z^{jm}-\sum_{j=1}^nz^{jm}
\stackrel{\ast}{=}z^0-z^n=0,$$
where $\ast$ holds because most terms of the two sums cancel out. Clearly $1-z^m\neq0$ so then the sum itself must equal $0$.